# How do I send a newsletter to 2000 emails on a shared server?

Tags: apache-2.2, email, shared-hosting

Consider this scenario:

- I'm running Magento 1.4 Community Edition
- I have a newsletter that I'm sending out 2 times per week
- My list has 2000 subscribers
- I'm on a shared hosting plan (linux on apache 2.2 with Cpanel)
- My hosting provider limits me to 6 emails/minute

How can I send 2000 emails x 2 times/week x 4 weeks/month in the above scenario?
Is there a server configuration I can ask my hosting company to make? Any software that can temporize the email send?

Comment: One at a time, at least if you want to avoid being marked a spammer.

Comment: My calculator tells me you can do that in 6 hours.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers, Jeff: any software recommendations for sending 2000 emails one at a time?

Answer (score 2):

If you have that many people this is where you start to look at using an external 3rd party service to handle newsletters for you.  They have already figured all of the SPAM stuff out and won't remove your shared hosting account for abuse of their mail servers.  Potentially more important is these newsletter providers have figured out how to deal with the legal requirements of the CAN-SPAM act, etc.

A simple Google search should yield some usable solutions.

Comment: I appreciate the info on Spam and all that and I don't mean to be rude, but I was asking for a server side solution (config or software), not a "google it" solution

Comment: And I was trying to give you a hint to read the FAQ as product recommendations are expressly off-topic here on ServerFault, so this is something you should be "Googling" or working with a vendor for.  Not to mention a shared hosting environment usually does not have the capacity to send that many e-mails.

Answer (score 0):

Mailchimp.com has a free service to send email marketing. It is can-spam compliant, as long as you have double opted-in subscribers.

Comment: the list is entirely comprised of customers and people who opted in through my Magento store. I also have unsubscribe in the email body